# Best way of expressing Camel route

Tags: apache-camel

If X is false I want to route to A, if X is true I want to route to A and B

I tried to write something like

```
from(?)
.choice()
   .when( X )
      .multicast().to(A,B).end()
   .otherwise() // I get a (compile) error underlined here saying 'otherwise() is not on type ProcessorDefinition
      .to( A )
```

it doesn't like it
I suspect this isn't the best way of phrasing this

basically I always want to route to (A) and if that condition is there I also want to route to (B)

what is the best way of expressing this in Camel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `endChoice()` at the end of your `when()` clause and it'll work...

see http://camel.apache.org/why-can-i-not-use-when-or-otherwise-in-a-java-camel-route.html

Answer (score 1):

See this FAQ about the choice: https://camel.apache.org/why-can-i-not-use-when-or-otherwise-in-a-java-camel-route.html

You can also use dynamic recipient list and compute the endpoints to route to. Then you can return 1 or 2 depending on the conditions: http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html

Answer (score 0):

If you always want your message to go to route A, then do not include it in the choice clause

```
from(?)
.to( A )
.choice()
   .when( X )
      to(B).end()
```

Something like above should suffice your case. Also read the articles that Claus has given in his answer.

Regarding your compilation error, remove the end() after the when clause. end() causes the choice() clause to be finished but you then use otherwise() clause while choice has already been closed.

Comment: this is great. 

Is there a risk that if on going to A the exchange gets modified - e.g type changed that it risks being the wrong type when it gets to the choice section?

Comment: maybe yes, that could happen

Comment: hmm. in that case I guess multicast is necessary

perhaps from().choice().multicast.to(B).end().to(A) would be best

Comment: i don't think multicast inside the choice would do anything since you have only one endpoint defined inside that clause and eventually you would end up with the route that you have written in your question

Comment: the point being if point B turns the IN of the exchange to some other type then it will screw things up when it gets to A. I was hoping that multicast would 'clone' the exchange so it doesn't mater what happens after it gets sent to B

Answer (score 0):

I have found that expressing your routes using the XML notation is a lot more concise in meaning.

For instance with the Java DSL people often make the mistake of not calling, or even adding 'endChoice()' and 'end()' like you have in your example; Sometimes you will also face an issue with Camel's Route Builder which is currently a limitation due to Java's Generics.

Unfortunately using XML comes with the cost of using XML :)